# Amazon EC2 has stopped showing public ip and public dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2 has suddenly stopped showing Public DNS and Public IP  on my instance. How can i retrieve them? I am unable to connect using putty or winSCP because of this. Kindly HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the instance running and does it have a private IP?  What do the status checks show (tab at bottom of instance details)?

Also, if the instance is otherwise healthy, try assigning an elastic ip to the instance and accessing it that way.

Otherwise if the instance is running and passing status checks, you should submit feedback (link at bottom of status check page) to open a request for AWS to give a hand.

Comment: well, thanks for the reply Beel, in fact i have been experimenting with Amazon EC2 for over a month now - trying to access my .WAR file through a browser (URL) but in vain. In this process, some how i lost the public IP. Yes i was able to retrieve the same after assigning the Elastic IP. If possible can you please throw some light on my 2nd problem : accessing my .WAR file through a URL. I deployed the war file through winSCP, and tomcat deployed the warfile (created a folder with the name of the war file). Now how can I access this??.

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you would, please post a new question with the specifics of the war issue.  Version of tomcat and whatever other info you might have.  I believe tomcat starts on port 8080 by default, so you'd need to open that port among other things. Best to post a separate question and let the TC mavens help.

Comment: OK, looks like you already tried that and didn't get much of a reply.  Mostly b/c folks didn't really know what you were asking.  Be as specific as possible and make the task that you're trying to achieve be as simple as possible and oriented toward your abilities.    In your case, have you gotten any tomcat app running (like the samples)?  What process did you follow (provide URL to tutorial / etc)?  What did you try?  What failed?  Error messages / results?  Create a new question or update your old one with some info to get the TC guys started.  HTH.

Comment: I tried all possibilities, ultimately i created a new instance on amazon and now i am able to deploy and access the same. Looks like there were some config problems while creating the instance.

Answer (score 0):

How come? For me those still there.. You can also assign elastic IP for your instance. Or get connection info by select instance and press "connect" button. Check also that you have required ports open in your security group settings and your instance is running.